# ¿Es correcto decir "Las rencillas llegan ya hasta las sentencias" o debería ser "Las rencillas llegan ya hasta 'a' las sentencias"?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

Leo este fragmento:

> El bloqueo de la renovación del Consejo General del Poder Judicial -el órgano de Gobierno de los jueces que designa a los responsables de los principales tribunales españoles- tras el fracaso del pacto impulsado por Pedro Sánchez, está detrás de la explosión de ánimos entre la cúpula judicial: "**Las rencillas llegan ya hasta las sentencias**", asegura un alto cargo de la judicatura con plaza en el Tribunal Supremo.
>
> <sub>[La cúpula judicial está rota: angustia, recados por escrito y lágrimas en el último pleno del consejo](https://www.eldiario.es/politica/Angustia-lagrimas-tension-cupula-judicial_0_841666235.html), Gonzalo Cortizo, 1 diciembre 2018</sub>

Y no deja de sonarme coja la frase que puse en negrita. Pienso que si no estuviera un *hasta*, la frase sería:

> Las rencillas llegan ya **a** las sentencias.

Al haber esta preposición veo que entra en sustitución de *a*, cuando a mi entender debería ser complementaria para designar más información, con lo que diríamos:

> Las rencillas llegan ya **hasta a** las sentencias.

¿Estoy en lo cierto? Veo en el artículo [*Ir por agua o ir a por agua*](http://www.rae.es/consultas/ir-por-agua-o-ir-por-agua) de la RAE reflexiones sobre el uso de dos preposiciones seguidas (varía según en España o Hispanoamérica) y no deduzco límites al respecto.

Comment: A mi eso que dices  me suena rarísimo pero he visto esta frase que al parecer es correcta y ya no sé que pensar: «Pueden condenarlo a hasta 10 años de cárcel.» No estoy seguro de si se puede extrapolar a tu caso.

Comment: Estoy pensando que si se utiliza como adverbio podría ser como dices, si sustituimos *hasta* por *incluso* diriamos: «Las rencillas llegan ya **incluso** a las sentencias.». Si la tomamos como preposición me sigue pareciendo raro

Comment: A nosotros los hispanoamericanos nos suenan rarísimas esas "a" adicionales (dobles preposiciones). Cuando para los de España es común decir "vamos **a** **por** el..." nosotros solo decimos "vamos **por** el..." Tal vez por eso te parezca que hace falta, pero para mi una sola preposición es suficiente. El uso de dos preposiciones me suena raro. (no estoy diciendo que sea incorrecto porque no se si lo es o no)

Answer (score 1):

Yo diría que es

> Las rencillas llegaron **hasta** las sentencias.

En el Fundéu hay un ejemplo con *[el día siguiente](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/el-dia-siguiente-al-dia-siguiente/)*.

Fíjate que con otras preposiciones no pondrías **a** delante:

> Las rencillas existen **desde** las sentencias.
>
> Las rencillas existen **para** las sentencias.

Comment: Sí, pero fíjate en el matiz importante de que estamos hablando de la construcción gramatical _llegar a_, que es diferente de simplemente _llegar_.

Comment: No me cuadra el argumento citado, pero si estoy de acuerdo en usar una sola preposición.  "Las rencillas llegaron **a** las sentencias" o "Las rencillas llegaron **hasta** las sentencias".